# When I create a list that holds the "id" values of other database tables, I cannot reach the "name" values for the related tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

I have a class named "ODL"

Which holds values of :

```
       {
         public int ODLId { get; set; }
         public string ODLName { get; set; }
         public int? RefODLId { get; set; }
         public int VehicleTypeId { get; set; }
         public int MotorTypeId { get; set; }
         public int GearboxTypeId { get; set; }
         public int DoorId { get; set; }
         public int VehicleLengthId { get; set; }
         public string ProjectName { get; set; }

       }
```

In another class which its name is "ODLModel" and used as a Model Class.
In this Model class there is a "List ODLs" property.

So now I can raech the ID values of VehicleType, MotorType etc.. in a foreach loop.

```
          @foreach (var odl in Model.ODLs)
           {
            <tr>
                <td>@odl.ODLName</td>
                <td>@odl.VehicleLengthId</td> 
                <td>@odl.MotorTypeId</td> 
!!! In here I dont want to show Id values but I would like to reach 
the related tables VehicleLength.cs etc and take their "Name" values 
and print it in here !!!
                    .....                                                                 
            </tr>
           }

    </tbody>
```

As I said, I'd like to show the "name" values in VehicleType.cs, MotorType.cs etc.

Im using EntityFramework, and all of my classes referenced as ID properties in ODL.cs are related to a table.

```
        public DbSet<VehicleType> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MotorType> MotorTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GearboxType> GearboxTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Door> Doors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VehicleLength> VehicleLengths { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ODL> ODLs { get; set; }
```

Comment: Any values you want to display should already be in your model. The view is no place to go and retrieve any extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to get properties of related items you have to change your ODL class. Instead of declaring `int ID` props you need to declare "navigation properties". You can read more about it at [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#relationships-in-ef)
And your ODL class will look like that:

```
{
     public int ODLId { get; set; }
     public string ODLName { get; set; }
     public int? RefODLId { get; set; }
     public virtual VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
     public virtual MotorType MotorType { get; set; }
     public virtual GearboxType GearboxType{ get; set; }
     public virtual Door Door { get; set; }
     public virtual VehicleLength VehicleLength { get; set; }
     public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

And you will be able to call it like:

```
var odl = ... // get ODL entity from DbSet
odl.VehicleType.Name
odl.GearboxType.SomeProperty
```

Comment: So when I have to map this class with modelBuilder.Entity<> what should I do?

Comment: @Burak my answer contains a link to documentation (which has a section called "Configuring or mapping relationships"). Did you read it?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry missed that part

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I made it done. I just add also "Id" columns which gives a refference to related tables. Thank you for your explanation.